# Do we always use F test in multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test, f-test

Since the F test deals with testing multiple categories/features/independent variables, do we always use a F test in determining if the independent variables are significant in **multiple linear regression**? Or not always?

It would make sense since T/Z test only tests 1 variable's significance at a time, so would not be applicable here (only in simple linear regression maybe).

Comment: The (two-sided) $t$ test is a special case of the $F$ test ($t^2$ follows an $F$ ratio distribution).  This is a hint about some special cases where an $F$ test would not be used.

Comment: So if i were to translate that, is it "you would not always use the F test. in one sided tests you would use the T test"?

Comment: Yes, that's one situation.

Answer (score 2):

No, such a test will not *always* be used.

1. There are for sure situations in which it is crystal clear from background knowledge even before seeing the data that the involved explanatory variables are connected to the response. In such situations a precise strength of effect (and quantifying uncertainty) is of interest, but a test of a null hypothesis of "no relation" isn't of interest as rejection will not be informative beyond what is already known.
2. There is a considerable number of statisticians these days who oppose the use of statistical hypothesis tests and the notion of significance quite generally. These people may advocate Bayesian methods and may not run F-tests.
3. Model assumptions behind the F-test may be violated to the extent that it should not be trusted. Bootstrap/resampling, nonparametric, or robust techniques may be used instead.

Comment: +1 for interesting (and correct) comments, though I saw the question as t vs F, as if classical hypothesis testing of some kind was a given.

Comment: @Dave Fair enough, I now see that this reading also makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A two-sided t-test of one regression coefficient is equivalent to an F-test of nested models where one model contains the variable with that coefficient and the other model contains the same variables except for that one. In some sense, whenever you run a two-sided t-test of one regression coefficient, you are doing an F-test, even if you think of it in terms of a t-test.

I assume that Casella/Berger shows the equivalence of t-stats and F-stats somewhere.

Casella, George, and Roger L. Berger. *Statistical inference*. Cengage Learning, 2021.